# error in password validation with regex in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to validate the devise password for my ruby on rails 6 application. It works perfectly but when I add the "/" sign inside the allowed signs it shows me the following error:

/app/models/user.rb:26: premature end of char-class: /(?=.{8,})(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*[$#*/
/home/jeff/Desktop/medic/app/models/user.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ')'
...*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*[$#*/])^[^&|]+$/)

my validation has restrictions for the user to enter at least one lower case, one upper case, one number, signs like $#*/ and excluding signs like |&

this is my validation:

```
  validate :password_uppercase
  def password_uppercase
    return if !!password.match(/(?=.{8,})(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*[$#*/])^[^&|]+$/)
    errors.add :password, ' password dont match'
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is really just a typo, but a tricky one, worth pointing out.  You need to escape the forward slash in the final lookahead's character class:

```rb
password.match(/(?=.{8,})(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*[$#*\/])^[^&|]+$/)
#                                                                     ^^^ change is here
```

This is because you have specified `/` as the delimiter in the call to `match`.

Comment: Technically its really because the OP is using a regex literal delimited with `/` instead of for example `%r{ ... }` or the constructor.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought it could be clarified a bit that the fact its being passed to `match` is really not that relevant in this case.

Comment: Yes, it would be a problem for _any_ Ruby function accepting a regex literal.

Answer (score 0):

Your slash is special symbol - it actually marks end of regex. Escape it via backslash